How to capture Android keyboard 'Next Action ' keycode in TypeScript
Trying to capture Keyboard 'Next Action' for my application requirement.
Added 'Keydown' event listener to the page body, but still not able to capture.
Any pointers on this would be of great help.
Solution to capture keycode of keyboard next action

can you share more details? like do you want to move to next textfield from keyboard?

We need to capture the keycode of the NextAction button on Keybaord.
